# Const objects with reference semantics

Tags: c++, const-correctness

I have a class that the user uses to interface with a system. This class uses Pimpl to hide its internals, so its only actual member is a reference to the real, hidden object that does all the work.

Because the class has reference semantics, it's usually passed around by value much like a pointer. That leads to a problem with `const` correctness. You can break the `const` nature of the class very easily by simply copying a `const` value into a non-`const` value. And there's no way to avoid that than to prevent copying altogether.

I want to be able to return `const` values of these, which preserves the `const` nature of the object. *Without* creating a new class or something.

Basically I want to prevent this from working:

```
struct Ref
{
    int &t;
    Ref(int &_t) : t(_t) {}
};

Ref MakeRef(int &t) { return Ref(t); }

int main()
{
    int foo = 5;
    const Ref r(foo);
    const Ref c(r);            //This should be allowed.
    Ref other = MakeRef(foo);  //This should also be allowed.
    Ref bar(r);                //This should fail to compile somehow.

    return 0;
}
```

After all, it would fail to work if I did it directly:

```
int &MakeRef(int &t) {return t;}

int main()
{
    int foo = 5;
    const int &r(foo);
    const int &c(r);            //This compiles.
    int &other = MakeRef(foo);  //This compiles.
    int &bar(r);                //This fails to compile.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can make the copy constructor private.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Then nobody could copy it for any reason.

Comment: What about deleting the copy constructor and creating a constructor that accepts non-const references?

Comment: @syam: You would then be unable to copy temporaries *and* unable to construct one `const` object to another. Thus, I could never return a `const T` by value.

Comment: Just for completeness can you also add a use case example where copying should be allowed?

Comment: Ah right, I somehow skipped the part where you say "preserve the constness". As far as I can tell, a hierarchy of classes is the solution (base `ConstRef` + derived `Ref` with the appropriate accessors) but unfortunately that doesn't answer your question since you explicitly don't want that.

Comment: I think you're conflating two things. Just because a class uses Pimpl doesn't mean it has reference semantics. Imagine the copy constructor copied the Pimpl data to the new class. Now copying has two distinct objects representing the value and the const issue is fixed: `const T x; T(x);` is fine because the original object isn't modified. On the other hand, reference semantics means that the state is shared. This again has nothing to do with Pimpl, which is just a way of representing internal data. (1/2)

Comment: So does your class have reference semantics by design or does it have it by accident? I think one of these things is irrelevant and should be removed. Hope that makes sense. (2/2)

Comment: @GManNickG: "*Just because a class uses Pimpl doesn't mean it has reference semantics.*" I never said that it did. The stuff about being a Pimpl class is in a completely different paragraph from the stuff about reference semantics. And yes, it has reference semantics by design. And it's Pimpl by design; I don't want everyone including the details of the implementation for these things.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Okay, that just seemed to be the implication.

Comment: It would be nice if C++ had a keyword to propagate constness to a non-aggregate member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible.  It's not possible for these 2 lines to behave differently:

```
const Ref c(r);            //This should be allowed.
Ref bar(r);                //This should fail to compile somehow.
```

Both lines will execute through the same code path, they will both execute through the same copy constructor (yours or automatically generated).  The only difference is the former will result in a const final variable.

The unfortunately reality is that even if you managed to prevent the above from compiling in your desired case, someone could simply do the following to circumvent your protection:

```
const Ref c(r);
Ref &bar = (Ref&)c;
```

If you're trying to prevent other people from doing nasty things to your class, you'll need to find an alternative to using a reference to a local variable.  If you're just worried about yourself, then just don't do anything you shouldn't :)

Comment: Oops.  I updated my code above.  `Ref &bar = (Ref&)c;` will just cast a const object to non-const reference of that const object.  There is no prevention.

Comment: That's like saying that `const`-correctness doesn't exist because someone can always `const`-cast around it (or in your case, C-style cast). That's deliberate misuse, not the accidental misuse that `int &bar(r)` prevents.

Comment: That's one of my points.  Why is the OP trying to prevent this?  Is it just him trying to save himself from himself, or is he trying to prevent an unscrupulous person from circumventing his security?  It's alot of effort to save himself from himself.

Comment: "*Why is the OP trying to prevent this?*" You may as well be asking why we have const-correctness *at all*.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the same issue that comes from conflating `const T*` and `T* const`: the mutability of the reference and the referent are distinct. There are valid use cases in C++ for all four possible combinations. I would make distinct types for "reference to T" and "reference to const T":

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Ref
{
    T &t;
    Ref(T &_t) : t(_t) {}
    Ref(const Ref<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>& other) : t(other.t) {}
};

template <typename T>
Ref<T> MakeRef(T& t) { return {t}; }

template <typename T>
Ref<const T> MakeConstRef(const T& t) { return {t}; }

int main()
{
    int foo = 5;
    auto r = MakeConstRef(foo);
    auto c = r;                 // This is allowed.
    auto other = MakeRef(foo);  // This is also allowed.
    Ref<const int> baz = other; // This works, too.
    Ref<int> bar = c;           // This fails to compile, as desired.
}
```

[Live example at ideone](http://ideone.com/hEjV0n).

Comment: It's a Pimpl class; it doesn't expose its privates as some kind of template argument.

Comment: @NicolBolas: The point stands that this is easiest to implement with separate types for reference-to-const and reference-to-mutable, with reference-to-mutable implicitly convertible to reference-to-const. I implemented the two types the easy way with a template, you may need two explicit types.

Comment: `Ref<int> &bar = (Ref<int>&)c;` ?

Comment: @MattHouser It's _supposed_ to fail - that was a design requirement.

Comment: @MattHouser: `Ref<int> &bar = (Ref<int>&)c;` That yields undefined behavior. `Ref<int>` and `Ref<const int>` have no relationship to one another. You may as well have cast an `int&` to a `float&`.

Answer (score 0):

CV-modifers in general, do not move past a reference or pointer from within an class/struct definition.  This is because it is not an aggregate part of the object, so technically, you are not really acting upon the object, just something that it is pointing at.

What you will have to do is roll your own constness like this:

```
struct constRef
{
    int const& _t;
    constRef(int const& rxo) : _t(rxo) {}
    constRef(constRef const& rxo) : _t(rxo._t) {}

    int const & t() const { return _t; }
    static constRef Make(int const & t) { return t; }
};

struct Ref
{
    int& _t;
    Ref(int& ro) : _t(ro) {}
    Ref(Ref const& rxo) : _t(rxo._t) {}
    operator constRef() const { return constRef(_t); }

    int& t() { return _t; }
    static Ref Make(int& t) { return t; }
};


int main()
{
    int foo = 5;
    Ref foo2(foo);               
    constRef r(foo2);            // non-const -> const         This compiles.
    constRef c(r);               // const -> const             This compiles.
    Ref other = Ref::Make(foo);  // non-const -> non-const     This compiles
    Ref bar(r);                  // const -> non-const         This fails to compile

    return 0;
}
```

This allows for automatic one way conversion between non-const to const type through the `Ref::operator constRef() const` conversion function.  A working model can be found [here](http://ideone.com/hhIcwy).

The only problem with this is that any type of operations that are correct for const objects would have to the signatures duplicated and the bodies point at the const class's implementation.

A possible way of getting around this would be inheritance, but doing so will probably get even more messy and problematic, not to mention will reduce the compilers ability to optimise.